# replace texbox values inside an html template

Tags: asp.net

i have some textboxes.. when 'preview' button is clicked it goes to another page which contains an html template.. i need to replace the textbox entered values inside the template.. how will i code it using asp.net? 
The html template is

```
<table width="450" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="bg" bgcolor="red">
<tr>                                            
    <td width="90" valign="top" class="bg" bgcolor="#ffffff">
        <h2 style="width: 642px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i><font color="#333333" face="Geneva, Arial" size=2.5>From:</font>&nbsp;&nbsp; 
            [mg-from]<br/>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color="#333333" face="Geneva, Arial" size=2.5>To:</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
            [mg-to]<br/>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color="#333333" face="Geneva, Arial" size=2.5>Subject:</font> 
            [mg-subject]</i></h2>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

i need to replace [mg-from] in the html template with txtfrom.text value which is given in first page
how will i code it using asp.net?

Comment: You read the template file, place it on a StringBuilder, and them you can use the Replace to replace that part of your code.

Comment: can u pls help me how to code it the preview.aspx page?

Comment: PLSSSS HELP ME.... CAN U PLS CODE ME HOW TO DO IT IN THE preview.aspx PAGE?

Comment: @user1844553 you can find the answer by google it

Answer (score 0):

try this out

```
     FileStream fs = new FileStream(**TemplateFileNamegoesHere**,FileMode.Open);

    StreamReader fr = new StreamReader(fs);
    string data = fr.ReadToEnd();
    string data=data.Replace(" [mg-from]", txtfrom.text );
```

it will replace the "[mg-from]" to given txtfrom.text value
try and let me know

Comment: @user1844553 try this and let me know?

Comment: but the textboxes are in another page......   i googled many...but didnt find any  :(.....

Comment: public partial class EmployeePortal_CommunicationPreview : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      

        System.IO.FileStream fs = new FileStream("~/Auto-Emails/Internalcommunication.htm", FileMode.Open);

        StreamReader fr = new StreamReader(fs);
        string data = fr.ReadToEnd();
        string data = data.Replace(" [mg-from]", txtfrom.text);

    }
 here the from.text is of the other page

Comment: @user1844553 can you explain it more

Comment: @user1844553 can you explain your problem a bit more . so that i can help you

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class EmployeePortal_CommunicationPreview : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        System.IO.FileStream fs = new FileStream("~/Auto-Emails/Internalcommunication.htm", FileMode.Open);

        StreamReader fr = new StreamReader(fs);
        string data = fr.ReadToEnd();
        string from  = data.Replace(" [mg-from]", txtfrom.text);

    }
}
```

here the txtfrom.text belongs to the first page... i need to pass the txtfrom of the first page to the second page replacing [mg-from]... how will i do ??